# How to pass range object in Custom 'whenFormulaSatisfued' function in Google Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a custom function that will highlight a cell if its length is greater than 850. I have written the below code:

```
colIndex = getColByName('Response');
var range = sheet.getRange(1, colIndex, sheet.getLastRow());
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenFormulaSatisfied(`=LEN(${range})>850`)
    .setBackground("yellow")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules.push(rule);
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
```

Where getColByName() gets the index of the column using a header. The output of this function looks like this:

[image]

which does not solve my requirement.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about modifying as follows?

#### From:

```
.whenFormulaSatisfied(`=LEN(${range})>850`)
```

#### To:

```
.whenFormulaSatisfied(`=LEN(${range.getA1Notation()})>850`)
```

- `var range = sheet.getRange(1, colIndex, sheet.getLastRow());` returns the Range object. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

#### Reference:

- [getA1Notation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation)